# Iterating a dictionary key value and averaging with known count

Tags: python, python-3.7

As a beginner in python,Im still trying to grasp the concept of dictionary count/loops better. So i've created a sample data to get my question across clearly. Below i have an unordered list of dictionaries containing the revenue information of a few shops. My question is, how do i get the average revenue of each shop - based on the count of reported revenue, reported by these shops?

```
     #Given data 
     revenue_list_of_dictionaries:
     [{'shop_ID': 1,
       'revenue': 15000},
      {'shop_ID': 2,
       'revenue': 12000},
      {'shop_ID': 1,
       'revenue': 8500},
      {'shop_ID': 3,
       'revenue': 5000}
      {'shop_ID': 1,
       'revenue': 3500}]

     data = revenue_list_of_dictionaries

     result = {}

     # Executing code to find total revenue for each shop ID
     for revenue_list in data:
         shop_ID = revenue_list['shop_ID']
         revenue_per_month = revenue_list['revenue']
         if shop_ID not in result:
             result[shop_ID] = revenue_per_month
         else:
             result[shop_ID] += revenue_per_month
```

Running the code above will give me:

```
         {'1':27000,
          '2':12000,
          '3':5000}
```

Based on each shop reporting count:

```
         {'1':3,
          '2':1,
          '3':1}
```

How do i find the average of each revenue reported so that my output will return the following:

```
         {'1': 9000,
          '2': 12000,
          '3': 5000}
```

Comment: create a dictionary with key as shop id but value as list of revenues, then calculate the average at the end. the idiomatic way for this is via `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Ich you want to overengineer it, you could use a `Counter` to count the amout of shops and then just compute the average..

Answer (score 1):

If the total revenue is called `a` and the count `b` and they both have the same keys (which they have to), you can use a dict comprehension to calculate the average revenue `c`:

```
c = {key: value/b[key] for key, value in a.items()}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm on mobile rn and can't test, but this should be the solution in pure Python

Comment: This will work fine if the OP wants to ammend his/her current approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate your current approach to work, then [user8408080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376997/iterating-a-dictionary-key-value-and-averaging-with-known-count/53377102#53377102)'s approach will work just fine.

Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments by [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376997/iterating-a-dictionary-key-value-and-averaging-with-known-count/53377102#comment93629647_53376997), you can collect the revenues with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), storing them as lists, then calculate the mean at the end:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

revenues = [
    {"shop_ID": 1, "revenue": 15000},
    {"shop_ID": 2, "revenue": 12000},
    {"shop_ID": 1, "revenue": 8500},
    {"shop_ID": 3, "revenue": 5000},
    {"shop_ID": 1, "revenue": 3500},
]

counts = defaultdict(list)
for revenue in revenues:
    counts[revenue['shop_ID']].append(revenue['revenue'])

print({k: mean(v) for k, v in counts.items()})
# {1: 9000, 2: 12000, 3: 5000}
```

You could also have a `collections.defaultdict()` of [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and store the revenues and counts simultaneously:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

revenues = [
    {"shop_ID": 1, "revenue": 15000},
    {"shop_ID": 2, "revenue": 12000},
    {"shop_ID": 1, "revenue": 8500},
    {"shop_ID": 3, "revenue": 5000},
    {"shop_ID": 1, "revenue": 3500},
]

counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for revenue in revenues:
    shp, rev = revenue['shop_ID'], revenue['revenue']
    counts[shp]['revenue'] += rev
    counts[shp]['count'] += 1

print({k: v['revenue'] / v['count'] for k, v in counts.items()})
# {1: 9000.0, 2: 12000.0, 3: 5000.0}
```

**Note:** In the first example I used [`statistic.median()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to calculate the mean. You can also use `sum(v) / len(v)` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without python packages, as follows:

```
result = {}
CountList = []

for dic in revenue_list_of_dictionaries:
    result.setdefault(dic.values()[0], 0)
    result[dic.values()[0]] += dic.values()[1]
    CountList.append(dic.values()[0])

#returning an average of all shop_Id revenues
for k, value in result.items():
    result[k] = value/CountList.count(k)

print result
#{1: 9000, 2: 12000, 3: 5000}
```